# redirict with javascript or php to gmail.com when hit the submit button

Tags: javascript, php

I've this form:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://gmail.com"       
    onsubmit="setTimeout(function () { window.location.reload(); }, 10)">
 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
 <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">

</div> 
<input type="submit" value="verzenden" class="btn btn-  primary" />
</form>
```

I want that if someone clicks on the button, he/she will redirect to gmail.com
I try target blank, but it doesn't work, does someone know a good manner to redirect with javascript or php?

EDIT: I want that if someone hit the button he/she will redirect to a new tab.

Comment: what do you mean by redirect? are you trying to send the form data to gmail.com or do you just want to send the user to the gmail.com page?

Comment: I try to redirict the user to gmail.com (in a new tablad) this form is for changin password

Comment: also, what is the purpose of reloading the page 10 milliseconds after the form is submitted?

Comment: how does this form change a password? you have set up the action of the form to be "http://gmail.com" (the front page of GMail). unless you're an official GMail developer (which I highly doubt) I really can't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I've a completely php script for changing password it works perfect. I only want for the user that he/she can go more easy to gmail.com :)

Comment: so you want to redirect a user to GMail after their password has been changed in your local system via this form?

Comment: no, i want the user  will redirict to gmail.com when hit the button in a new tabblad

Comment: but what does this form do? why do you have an email field there?

Comment: thanks for saying :) I have to improve my english! 
what do you mean with: "Back in"?

Comment: Bodyflex that information isn't necessary for a redirict I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree that this scenario is a bit strange as I have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish but, if you just want to open gmail.com in a new window when the form is submitted, this should suffice:

```
<form onsubmit="window.open('http://gmail.com')">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">E-mailadres</label>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" id="email">
    </div> 

    <input type="submit" value="verzenden" class="btn btn-  primary" />
</form>
```

Comment: sorry but a new question again. perhaps you do not understand me but maybe you have again a nice answer for me.

is it possible to open the window in a script like:  <script> 
 function myFunction() {
  window.open('http://gmail.com')
  
 }
      </script>

Comment: and as onsubmit: onsubmit="myFuction"

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<input type="button" value="verzenden" class="btn btn-  primary"  onclick="move_to_gmail();"/>


<script>
function move_to_gmail(){
window.location = 'http://www.gmail.com';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, is that als possible with redirict to gmail in a new tablad?

Comment: if this would be the desired use, why do this with javascript instead of a normal link? btw, javascript functions and variables are written in camelCase + you forgot to close the script tag there.

Comment: because it doesn't work with normal link in form (I need a button) <a href="blabl.com"><input type="button" /></a> doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

with PHP, you could use

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/');
```

and with JavaScript, use

```
document.location.href="http://www.example.com";
```

Comment: Thanks, is that also possible with redirict to gmail in new page?

Answer (score 0):

To open a new window (if it's really a new window or a new tab is decided by the browser, you can't influence this), use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open):

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="http://gmail.com"       
    onsubmit="window.open('http://gmail.com');return false;">
```

`window.open('http://gmail.com');` opens gmail.com, `return false;` cancels the submitting of the form. This **won't** send the data from the form to gmail.com! Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/30d6em13/

Without JavaScript use `target="_blank"`

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" target="_blank" action="http://gmail.com">
```

This will open http://gmail.com in a new window/tab. But this **will** send the data entered into the form to gmail.com! Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/30d6em13/1/